SectionList in react-native showing blank spaces on scrolling
I am trying to show the list of contacts in react-native using SectionList component and the list that is going to be rendered is to be expected as given below:

But the List I am getting is not like this it is taking time to render and there are white spaces coming while rendering this list see the image below:

So what could be the problem and how can I solve it, here is my code using which I got the output, first I am fetching data in component <AllContactSectionList /> and here is the code for it:
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
import ContactSection from './ContactScetion';
import ContactSidebar from './ContactSidebar';

const AllContactSectionList = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
    const [initialCount, setCount] = useState(1000);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const sectionListRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const requestContactsPermission = async () => {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
                    {
                        title: 'Contacts',
                        message: 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
                        buttonPositive: 'Please accept',
                    }
                );
                if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    getAllContacts();
                }
            } else {
                getAllContacts();
            }
        };
        requestContactsPermission();
        Contacts.getCount().then(count => {
            setCount(count);
        });
    }, [getAllContacts, isFocused]);

    const getAllContacts = useCallback(() => {
        Contacts.getAll()
            .then((cont) => {
                const filteredData = cont.filter(item => /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(item.displayName));
                const sortedData = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
                    const displayNameA = a.displayName || '';
                    const displayNameB = b.displayName || '';
                    return displayNameA.localeCompare(displayNameB, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
                });
                const groupedData = groupContacts(sortedData);
                setContacts(groupedData);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }, [setContacts]);

    const groupContacts = (data) => {
        const groupedData = {};
        data.forEach((item) => {
            const firstLetter = item.displayName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
            if (!groupedData[firstLetter]) {
                groupedData[firstLetter] = [];
            }
            groupedData[firstLetter].push(item);
        });
        return Object.keys(groupedData).map((key) => ({
            title: key,
            data: groupedData[key],
        }));
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                    <ContactSection
                        navigation={navigation}
                        contacts={contacts}
                        sectionListRef={sectionListRef}
                        onDelete={handleDelete}
                        count={initialCount} />
                    <View style={styles.sidebarContainer}>
                        <ContactSidebar
                            sidebarTitle={contacts.map(item => item.title)}
                            sectionListRef={sectionListRef}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
        </View>
    );
};
export default AllContactSectionList;

From <AllContactSectionList /> Component I am sending props of contacts to the component <ContactSection/> and in this component I am rendering my list using the code below:
import { View, StyleSheet, SectionList, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
import sectionListGetItemLayout from 'react-native-section-list-get-item-layout';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import ContactSectionHeader from './ContactSectionHeader';
import ContactSectionItem from './ContactSectionItem';

const ContactSection = ({
    navigation,
    contacts,
    sectionListRef,
    onDelete,
    setContacts,
    count }) => {

    const getItemLayout = sectionListGetItemLayout({
        getItemHeight: () => 60,
        getSectionHeaderHeight: () => 25,
        getSectionFooterHeight: () => 0,
        getSeparatorHeight: () => 0 / PixelRatio.get(),
        listHeaderHeight: 0,
    });

    const listKeyExtractor = (item, index) => `item-${index}`;

    const renderItemFunc = ({ item, index }) => {
        const phoneNumber = item.phoneNumbers && item.phoneNumbers.length > 0 ? item.phoneNumbers[0] : {};
        const number = phoneNumber.number || 'No number';
        return (
            <ContactSectionItem
                title={item.displayName}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ContactDetails', { data: item })}
                onDelete={() => onDelete(item)}
                contactNumber={number}
                index={index}
            />
        );
    };

    const renderHeaderFunc = ({ section }) => {
        return (
            <ContactSectionHeader
                header={section.title}
            />
        );
    };

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SectionList
                    ref={sectionListRef}
                    keyExtractor={listKeyExtractor}
                    renderSectionHeader={renderHeaderFunc}
                    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
                    sections={contacts}
                    renderItem={renderItemFunc}
                // initialNumToRender={count}
                // maxToRenderPerBatch={count}
                // windowSize={21}
                />
            </View>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};
export default ContactSection;

This is the code to render my section list so this is can someone help me to achieve a smooth and responsive scrollable sectionList, also as you can see to get rid of blank spaces I tried to use props like initialNumToRender={count}, maxToRenderPerBatch={count} and windowSize={21} in sectionList after using these props I can get rid of blank spaces but the thing is the list hen taking time to render initially also when I click any list Item it is unresponsive and when I generate an APK file the APK file after being open gets crashed. So if you have any suggestions please help me. thank you.

This is happened when we have large set of data but we can boost the performance via some strategies and prevent from re-rendering.
Here is some things you can do to make it works.
1. You can pass these props to the SectionList:
decelerationRate="fast"
directionalLockEnabled={true}
disableVirtualization={true}

2. Don't use arrow function under the renderItem
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ContactDetails', { data: item })}

to
const onPressContact = useCallback((item)=> navigation.navigate('ContactDetails', { data: item }),[])

pass this to renderItem and call in ContactSectionItem
3. Convert item components to memo

I didn't understand your 3rd point - 3. Convert item components to memo?
which item component you are saying and how to  convert it into memo as I have never used memo can you give an example or something?

I have meomoized the item using a React.memo but still initially I got the whit space and on scrolling it is not smooth and it is taking time to render more items in the list so unable to scroll any further unless more items get rendered.
